# String replace in unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, string-matching

I am to remove some text after a number for example: 1.2.0_testing. I just want the number part which is 1.2.0. SO anything after the underscore needs to be removed.
Below is the code I am using:

```
echo $str | sed 's/_*//'
```

However the wildcard doesn't seem to work and I still get the full string. Can someone please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: That's not a wildcard, it's a [regular expression](https://www.google.ca/search?q=what+is+a+regular+expression)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for expensive forks to sed, awk, or - gasp! - perl. The shell can do this nicely:

```
$ str=1.2.0_testing
$ echo ${str%%_*}     # Remove longest part from the right matching _*
1.2.0
```

Learn all there is about built-in string manipulation with %, %%, #, ## in your fine shell manual. These remove from the right (percent) or left (hash) the shortest (single) or longest (double) match.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
echo $str | sed 's/_.*//'
```

`.` - Matches any single character.

`*` -   Matches zero or more occurrences of the previous character

So, `_.*` would represent 0 or more characters following `_`.

Comment: Forking sed to remove a few characters from the end of a shell string is an anti-pattern that should not be proliferated.